How can I determine the link budget, baud rate and bandwidth for a hypothetical satellite orbiting the Moon? Are my calculations path correct?
How can I determine the baud rate and bandwidth for a hypothetical satellite orbiting the Moon?
I am trying to calculate a link budget for a hypothetical Earth-Moon CubeSat. The parameters I am using are:

Distance: $384,400 \, \text{km}$
Frequency: $8.250 \, \text{GHz}$
Transmit Power ($ P_t $): $ 33 \, \text{dBm} $
Transmit Antenna Gain ($ G_t $): $ 18 \, \text{dBi}$
Receive Antenna Gain ($ G_r $): $ 74.66 \, \text{dBi} $ (Madrid 70 m Dish)
Miscellaneous Losses ($ L_{\text{misc}} $): $ 5.4 \, \text{dB}$
Data Rate: $ 1 \, \text{Mbps}$
Modulation: BPSK
Roll-Off Factor ($ \alpha $): $ 0.2 $
Noise Figure ($ NF $): $ 1 \, \text{dB} $

Here are my calculations:
Path Loss Calculation ($ L_p $):
$
   L_p = 20 \log(384,400) + 20 \log(8.250) + 92.44 \approx 222.46 \, \text{dB}.
   $
Received Power ($ P_r $):
Using the link budget equation:
$
   P_r = P_t + G_t + G_r - L_p - L_{\text{misc}}
   $
$
   P_r = 33 + 18 + 74.66 - 222.46 - 5.4 = -101.2 \, \text{dBm}.
   $
Baud Rate Calculation ($ f_{\text{baud}} $):
For BPSK:
$
   f_{\text{baud}} = \frac{\text{Data Rate}}{\log_2(M)} = \frac{1 \, \text{Mbps}}{1} = 1 \, \text{MBaud}.
   $
Bandwidth Calculation ($ BW $):
$
   BW = f_{\text{baud}} \times (1 + \alpha)
   $
$
   BW = 1 \, \text{MBaud} \times 1.2 = 1.2 \, \text{MHz}.
   $
However, I’ve also seen bandwidth calculated using Carson’s Rule as:
$
   BW_{\text{transmission}} = 2 \Delta f + f_{\text{baud}}.
   $
Which method is correct in this case?
Noise Power ($ P_n $):
I calculated the noise power as:
$
   P_n = -174 \, \text{dBm/Hz} + 10 \log_{10}(BW) + NF
   $
$
   P_n = -174 + 10 \log_{10}(1.2 \times 10^6) + 1
   $
$
   P_n = -174 + 60.79 + 1 = -112.21 \, \text{dBm}.
   $
Signal-to-Noise Ratio (SNR):
data rate is sufficient`?
$
   SNR = P_r - P_n = -101.2 - (-112.21) = -101.2 + 112.21 = 11.01 \, \text{dB}.
   $
The required SNR for BPSK is $ 9.6 \, \text{dB} $, so the link should work???
My Questions:

Is my approach to the link budget calculation correct?
How should I determine the bandwidth for BPSK: using $ BW = f_{\text{baud}} \times (1 + \alpha) $ or Carson’s Rule?
Is my data rate of $ 1 \, \text{Mbps} $ optimal for this link?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I am still learning!
Edit: The formulas for link budget and path loss were taken from Charles D. Brown's Elements of Spacecraft Design (pp. 468, 473, 478). However, it seems my SNR calculation is wrong....

Did you use ChatGPT to write this? Please be aware that ChatGPT is banned here

The ban is against using CharGPT to write answers.

@Starship I used to help me write the formulas for Stackoverflow format. But At the end I only needed to put $$ in each LateX line.

@Hobbes Incorrect. It bans content generated by AI, not just answers.

No, it doesn't. It says, "Generative artificial intelligence (a.k.a. GPT, LLM, generative AI, genAI) tools can be used to generate content for Space Exploration Stack Exchange, but this content must be properly referenced as per our guidance" That's not a ban on AI-generated content, it's a ban on unreferenced answers.  https://space.stackexchange.com/help/gen-ai-policy
